# Extract link from json

Tags: php, json

4 days ago Iam asking for how to [Extract the data from content of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344569/extract-the-data-from-content-of-html)

It is work and everything good but the problem is print all data, look like json:

```
{"post_id":"453298879","author_id":"1348","media_type":1,"images_src":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JpfhVqK.png","content":"Hello World!"}
```

Just want content of images_src . `http://i.imgur.com/JpfhVqK.png`

I'm trying to use **json_decode** but doesn't work.

Ps: there are no file of json, just variable content this json.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data =
   {"post_id":"453298879","author_id":"1348","media_type":1,"images_src":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JpfhVqK.png","content":"Hello
    World!"};
```

console.log(data.images_src)

```
data.image_src will output : 'http://i.imgur.com/JpfhVqK.png'
```

Comment: Nothing change, it is blank page, Maybe because I'm using curl to get this json. I will update this post. Thank you for help.

Comment: That is strange if you look here you can see it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/74dfya1d/. You need to assign your json object to a variable in order to fetch it.

Comment: Yes. it is work, Is there another way to get this without javascript because I'm using java to get this link from PHP.

Comment: You can get the json object as you like to. You only need to assign the returned object to the variable, in this case 'data'

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
$json = '{"post_id":"453298879","author_id":"1348","media_type":1,"images_src":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JpfhVqK.png","content":"Hello World!"}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data['images_src']);
```

Comment: It is return NULL, Maybe because I'm using curl to get this json. I will update this post. Thank you for help.